# Results from ip-api.com are not returned (finding ISP from IP address)

Tags: php, serialization, ip, file-get-contents

I am using the below code to receive ISP from given IP address. Till two days ago it worked fine, and I am pretty sure I changed nothing.

The API: http://ip-api.com/docs/api:serialized_php

I know that Unserialize is deprecated and should use JSON, but still it should work and would like to use this.

```
<?php
// IP to search
$rvrsipmx = '151.101.1.69';
$ispQuery = @unserialize(file_get_contents('http://ip-api.com/php/'.$rvrsipmx));
if($ispQuery && $ispQuery['status'] == 'success') {
echo 'ISP: ' . $ispQuery['isp'];

} else {
  echo 'ISP not found';
}
?>
```

For every query I receive **ISP not found**.
It works when given IP is submited to browser like this: 
http://ip-api.com/php/151.101.1.69

My **IP is not banned**, This was checked through their Unban function ip-api.com/docs/unban

var_export($ispQuery); returns value **false**

What am I doing wrong?

**SOLVED:** allow_url_fopen: off 
Changed to **on** and it works

Comment: Does the `file_get_contents` call in the script return what you're expecting? I have no idea of the terms of service for that site, but you could be getting blocked, or just having a connectivity issue. Also `unserialize` is definitely not deprecated.

Comment: i ran your script in a terminal here it is working perfectly fine

Comment: Forgot to mention. My IP is not banned, This was checked through their Unban function http://ip-api.com/docs/unban

@sietse85 Do you get the result: ISP: Fastly ?

Comment: yes i got that on the terminal

Comment: SOLVED: 
allow_url_fopen: off
Changed to on and it works

Comment: @sietse85 Thanks for checking and make me try other things. Really cant remember when I switched off this setting on server.

Comment: `and I am pretty sure I changed nothing.` ^^